# How to enforce "not-null" in OpenApi yaml files for Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator

To my understanding `nullable` is false by default, however this still doesn't do the trick for me.
I have some class, let's name it `SomeClass`:

```
SomeClass:
  type: object
  properties:
    filter:
      type: array
      items:
        type: object
        properties:
          name:
            type: string
          value:
            type: string
        required:
          - name
          - value
```

This class is used in an endpoint, such as:

```
/api/somePost:
post:
  operationId: somePost
  requestBody:
    required: true
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/SomeClass'
  responses:...
```

The generated interface is not generated with `@NotNull` (or equivalent). This is a problem because when using Spring Boot validator, I get exception for violating Liskov principle (A method overriding another method must not redefine the parameter constraint configuration...).
The reason for that is that I have added `@NotNull` to the endpoint's parameter in the controller's implementation, where the interface does not require it to be non-null. Question is, instead of removing the `@NotNull` from the endpoint, how can I get it to generate on the interface?